# Which is the best approach to query and join hive tables in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, hive

I have 6 tables in hive and I want through pyspark to extract their information and do some joins between them and then upload a final table in hive.

My way is :

1. Create a df for each table with `spark.sql`
2. Make the joins like `df_final= df_student.join(df_class, on=['account_id'], how='inner')`
3. `df_final.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("db.classroom")`

The reason why I am struggling is because I do not know if this is an efficient way. Also I saw `spark.sql.sqlcontext` but I could not understand the usage instead of `spark.sql`

Comment: why don't you just do `spark.sql("insert into db.classroom select * from df_student join df_class using(account_id)")`?

Comment: @mck I have to make 6 joins. Is it efficient with this way?

Comment: I think it is. I don't see any problems which makes it inefficient. No need to convert to dataframe if you just use spark.sql

Comment: `spark.sql("insert into db.classroom select * from df_student join df_class using(account_id)")`

`spark.sql("insert into db.classroom select * from db.classroom join df_teacher using(account_id,party_id)") `  

Can I refer to the table that I insert into and join with two columns like the above?

Comment: normally you can't because after joining, there will be additional columns which do not exist in the original table.

Comment: @mck Basically I want to have a standard table and join into it other tables so first I will join the student with class into classroom, after teachers into the new classroom table,after the schools into classroom. I want to end with a table which has inner joins from all other tables.

Comment: then you need to explicitly select the columns, and don't use `select *`. make sure that you select the columns that exist in `db.classroom`, and then the insert should work.